# Gnuplot: plot specific matrix from file with many matrices

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file, let's say 6 x 2 which contains the data of three 2 by 2 matrices:

```
1 2
3 2
1 5
6 2 
8 5 
2 7
```

Now I want to be able to plot specific matrices of that file. Like the matrix

```
1 5
6 2
```

For my other files where I have one dimensional data I use `::1::10` if I want to plot Data from the first ten lines.

Bit how can I do that for matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resembles [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45225079/7295599) with the difference that you don't have a single column file but already several matrices, but "glued" together. If you had them separated by two empty lines, you could easily address the individual matrices via `index` (check `help index`).

Nevertheless, you can address your data via `every` (check `help matrix every`).

So, there is *no need* for external tools, you can simply do it with *gnuplot only*, hence *platform-independently*.
The example below will split the data into four 2x3 matrices.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.0, Jan. 2015)

```
### split data into several matrices
reset session

$Data <<EOD
 1   2   3
 4   5   6
 7   8   9
10  11  12
13  14  15
16  17  18
19  20  21
22  23  24
EOD

m = 2
n = 3
set cbrange [0:25]
set key noautotitle

set multiplot layout 2,2
    do for [i=0:3] {
        set title sprintf("Matrix %d",i)
        plot $Data matrix u 1:2:3 every :::i*m::(i+1)*m-1 w image
    }
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could select the block/matrix of interest "manually" and then pass this preprocessed input to Gnuplot to visualize it. For example:

```
getMatrix(fName, i) = sprintf("<sed -n -e'%d,%dp' '%s'", 2*i-1, 2*i, fName)

plot getMatrix('test.dat', 2) matrix w image
```

Here, Gnuplot "sees" only the output of the `sed` command which filters from the file `test.dat` only lines 3 and 4, i.e., the matrix you show in your post.

EDIT:

The statement

```
getMatrix(fName, i) = sprintf("<sed -n -e'%d,%dp' '%s'", 2*i-1, 2*i, fName)
```

defines a function which for given file name and matrix index (assumed to be 1-based) constructs first a string containing the plotting command which is then passed to `plot`. For example, for `i=1` and file `test.dat`, the command looks like `<sed -n -e'1,2p' 'test.dat'`. If one instructs Gnuplot to plot such a "thing", it executes the command after the leading `<` and plots its output (instead of the entire file `test.dat`). In this particular case, `sed` extracts only lines with line numbers (1-based) from `1` to `2` (inclusive).

In order to extend this for matrices of general size `N` (assuming that the file being processed has corresponding number of columns), one could for example do:

```
unset key

getMatrix(fName, N, i) = sprintf("<sed -n -e'%d,%dp' '%s'", (i-1)*N + 1, i*N, fName)

do for [i=1:2] {
    plot getMatrix('test.dat', 10, i) matrix w image
    pause 5
}
```

The only change here is the extra parameter `N` denoting the size of the individual matrices and how the range of rows is calculated...

Comment: Can you explain the line `getMatrix(fName, i) = sprintf("<sed -n -e'%d,%dp' '%s'", 2*i-1, 2*i, fName)` in more detail. I do not see what happens here. What would I change if I have 10 matrices in a file which has size 100 x 10? Furthermore, I want to create a dynamic plot in order to see the evolution of the matrices. My approach is `do for [t=1:10]{
 getMatrix(fName, i) = sprintf("<sed -n -e'%d,%dp' '%s'", 2*i-1, 2*i, fName)
 plot getMatrix('test.dat', 10) matrix w image
 pause 1
}`. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm!

Comment: Can you add the case for non-symmetric matrices? What would it look like for a M x N matrix?